Confused about a fixed point in the space of bounded sequences.
Take the space $\ell^{\infty}$ and a mapping which transforms a sequence so that every element becomes a linear combination of the ones succeeding it, $f(s): s_i \mapsto a_0s_i + a_1s_{i+1} + ... + a_ns_{i+n}$. I want to show this is a Lipschitz function using the $\sup$ norm.
$\sup\{|f(s_i)-f(t_i)|: i \in \mathbb{N} \} \\ = \sup\{|(a_0s_i + a_1s_{i+1} + ... + a_ns_{i+n}) - (a_0t_i + a_1t_{i+1} + ... + a_nt_{i+n})|\} \\ = \sup|a_0(s_i-t_i) + a_1(s_{i+1}-t_{i+1}) + ... + a_n(s_{i+n}-t_{i+n})| \\ \leq |a_0|\sup|s_i-t_i| + |a_1|\sup|s_{i+1}-t_{i+1}| + ... + |a_n|\sup|s_{i+n}-t_{i+n}| \\ \leq (|a_0| + |a_1| + ... +|a_n|)\sup|s_i - t_i|$
The last inequality is supported because either $\sup|s_j - t_j|$ is in the remaining part of the sequence, or somewhere between 1 and j, so it must be less than or equal to the sup over the whole sequence. This means then that this function is a contraction given that $|a_0| + |a_1| + ... |a_n| < 1$. However, for a simple example with 3 terms, any fixed point would be a sequence that satisfies the equation $s_i = a_0s_i + a_1s_{i+1} + a_2s_{i+2}$, which can be solved to be a recurrence relation with roots $\frac{-a_1 \pm \sqrt{a_1^2-4a_2(1-a_0)}}{2a_2}$. For it to be a bounded sequence, these roots need to have absolute value less than one, but plotting it on desmos shows that there's no solution that solves both these cases. So I have a contraction map with no fixed points. Where did I go wrong?

The space you are talking about is $\ell^\infty$

The sequence of all $0$'s is the fixed point.

Your map is of the form $T = \sum_{k=0}^n a_k S^k$ where $S$ is the shift-to-the-left operator. Of course, it is Lipschitz: $|Tx-Ty| \leq |T| |x-y|$ where $|T|\leq \sum_k |a_k| |S^k|  = \sum_k |a_k|$ is the norm of $T$

The fixed points of $T$ are solutions of $Tx = x$ that is $(T-I)x = 0$. That is, the kernel of $T-I$, which is a whole (closed) vector subspace of $\ell^\infty$

@Jakobian I've only done undergraduate linear algebra and am working through my second semester of advanced calc/analysis, so excuse me if I'm thinking about this weirdly,, but from what I understand $T$ is an infinite circulant matrix with my $a_{i}$'s and $I$ the infinite identity matrix? How would I solve that equation then? If not a whole answer than a resource to point me in the right direction.

Keep it simple. The 2nd comment above (by @RobertIsrael) constitues an answer to your post.

@RobertIsrael I think I just made sense of one of my mistakes, I'm conflating a fixed point in this sense with the fixed points of iterating this function? Or are these also the same, and I'm simply out of my depths.. Although I can see how, especially since the fixed point is unique, that it must be the 0 sequence.

$0$ is always a fixed point of any linear operator.  If $|T| < 1$, so $|T x | \le |T| |x| < |x|$ when $x \ne 0$, then it is the unique fixed point.
